# matplotlib: why is LinearRegression line not showing up?

Tags: python, machine-learning

Using Geany IDE

when running `python file.py` command from `iTerm2`, I get the following 
error message:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/basic.py:1226: RuntimeWarning: internal gelsd driver lwork query error, required iwork dimension not returned. This is likely the result of LAPACK bug 0038, fixed in LAPACK 3.2.2 (released July 21, 2010). Falling back to 'gelss' driver.
  warnings.warn(mesg, RuntimeWarning)
A 12" pizza should cost: $13.68
```

'Here's my code:

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression 


    X = np.array([[6], [8], [10], [14], [18]]).reshape(-1,1)
    y = [7,9,13,17.5,18]

    # In[2]:
    model = LinearRegression()  # Create an instance of the estimator
    model.fit(X, y)  # Fit the model on the training data 

    # Predict the price of a pizza with a diameter that has never been                              seen before 
     test_pizza = np.array([[12]]) 
     predicted_price = model.predict(test_pizza)[0] 



     plt.figure()
     plt.title('pizza thing')
     plt.xlabel('x-axis diam')
     plt.ylabel('y-axis price dollar dollar')
     plt.plot(X,y, 'k.')
     plt.axis([0,25,0,25])
     plt.grid(True)
     plt.show()

     print('A 12" pizza should cost: $%.2f' % predicted_price) `
```

edit: added expected graph. thanks guys.

[Expected Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PX64H.png)

[GRAPH OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o09p.png)

update:[Accepted Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCC6g.png)

Comment: Please format the code for readability.  Also, include the errors with the question in case the external images are deleted.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about [ask].

Comment: Reformatted and added error message to text instead of image.

Comment: @user1224312424 Your code works fine, it's showing a dot plot. Do you want to draw a line?

Comment: your code is correct and will plot a scatter chart, what additional line do you expect to show up?

Comment: @hoefling added expected graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to draw the predicted results of `y` alongside `y`. To do so, you need to make few changes to your code:

- `predicted_price = model.predict(X)` instead of  `predicted_price = model.predict(test_pizza)[0]`
- add `plt.plot(X,predicted_price)` after `plt.plot(X,y, 'k.')`

---

Overall, here's how the code will look like after the changes:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression 
X = np.array([[6], [8], [10], [14], [18]]).reshape(-1,1)
y = [7,9,13,17.5,18]

# In[2]:
model = LinearRegression()  # Create an instance of the estimator
model.fit(X, y)  # Fit the model on the training data 

# Predict the price of a pizza with a diameter that has never been                              seen before 
#test_pizza = np.array([[12]])  
predicted_price = model.predict(X)


plt.figure()
plt.title('pizza thing')
plt.xlabel('x-axis diam')
plt.ylabel('y-axis price dollar dollar')
plt.plot(X,y, 'k.')
plt.plot(X,predicted_price)
plt.axis([0,25,0,25])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

print('A 12" pizza should cost: $%.2f' % predicted_price)
```